# Add optional argument to newcommand for integration dx

Tags: optional-arguments, integral

In my preamble I use
`\newcommand\dx{\,dx}`so that I can change formatting of all instances if it is needed.  What I would really like is to add an optional argument so that I can type `\dx` whenever I need it and `\dx[t]` whenever I need a dt in my integration so I can change variables at will without writing separate code for each.

Comment: `\newcommand\dx[1][x]{\,d#1}`

Comment: Better use a macro found on this site to type only the `d` with a correct spacing: `\newcommand*{\dd}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}` (the differential symbol should be typed in upshape) and type in your document  just  `\dd x`, `\dd t` &c.

Comment: @Bernard You know I disagree with your comment about “d” being upright. It's ***not*** the case in many typographical traditions.

Comment: @egreg: it was only my opinion, and I added this comment to explain why there was a \mathrm.

Comment: Thank you!  I know that there is some controversy over the typography.  The current style I need is without the upright d, but  when the paper goes to committee they may ask me to change it, so I just wanted this as a separate, editable, command.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While Bernard's advice may be preferred from a typesetting perspective, the direct answer to the OP's question concerning the use of an optional argument is

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\dx[1][x]{\,d#1}
\begin{document}
$a \dx$ versus $a \dx[t]$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 13):

I'd prefer something like

```
\newcommand{\dx}[1][x]{\mathop{}\!d#1}
```

that does the trick much better than adding `\,` explicitly.

But if you just define a macro for `d`, you get easier input:

```
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!d}
```

and then

```
\int f(x)\diff x
\int f(t)\diff t
```

Use `\dd` instead of `\diff` if you prefer. Compare with the syntax you propose

```
\int f(x)\dx
\int f(t)\dx[t]
```

and take your pick.

Comment: Could you add some explanation as to why "`\mathop{}\!` does the trick much better than adding `\,`"?

Comment: @Werner one can use it for Leibniz derivative notation.

Answer (score 7):

Just I was trying another approach...but there are users as good as the lightning that precedes me :-).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\newcommand{\df}[1]{\,\mathrm{d}{#1}}
\begin{document}

\[\int f(x)\df{x}, \int f(t)\df{t},\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or this with the slanted variables:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\newcommand{\df}[1]{\,d{#1}}
\begin{document}

\[\int f(x)\df{x}, \int f(t)\df{t},\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Check out the awesome package [diffcoeff](http://ftp.ntua.gr/mirror/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/diffcoeff/diffcoeff.pdf) with a lot of customizations. For your question, the following excerpt is quoted from the manual:

> diffcoeff provides a command \dl to write the ‘d’ in a differential in
> a manner consistent with the default form used in derivatives.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{diffcoeff}
\begin{document}
    $\dl x$\\
    $\dl x\dl3y$\\  
    $\dl x\dl3y = r\dl3r\dl3\theta$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### The `physics` package and its `\dd{}` command

Why re-invent the wheel:

```latex
\usepackage{physics}
\begin{document}
$ \dv{f}{x} $ uses $ \dd{x} $ 
\end{document}
```

[image]

This has all the nice spacing, can have autoscaling parentheses (if you use `\dd()` instead of `\dd{}`), and typesets the "d" in as an upright symbol (as it should be).

Comment: Because `physics` does a lot of bad things.

Comment: It's far from perfect, but it does touch on the issue of "Use a package that has some flaws" Vs "Re-invent the wheel".

Comment: “Some flaws” is, unfortunately, a gross understatement.

Comment: How many times I reinvented the wheel because I didn't know there was a wheel. I almost recreated the whole `derivative` package just by "hey ... I could do this ... hmm that would be nice ... hey I may use an optional argument and ... ohhh interesting ...". I only found out about `derivative` when I noticed I didn't have enough knowledge to automatize properly the mixed partial derivatives. On the other hand, I'd also say it's good to have many people knowing how to recreate wheels just in case everyone who knows it today disappear.

Comment: Re-inventing the wheel is a useful learning exercise, no doubt, but certainly not something to make a habit out of. I frequently stumble on packages after I have done my own rather comparatively poor job at unintentionally mimicking them. However, similar to building you own random number generator, encryption routine, or matrix multiplier, it is useful to learn from once, but in practice should only really be left to experts/professionals.